# Unattended signing of Reprepro packages with gpg-agent

Tags: repository, gnupg, unattended-processing, gpg-agent

For my SolydXK repository I'd like to add some packages available in Debian stretch-backports.

I've successfully setup the conf/distributions, conf/updates and FilterList files and the following command runs successfully when logged in to the server:

`reprepro -b /path_to_repository_basedir update`

When adding files to the repository I correctly have to fill in my gpg passphrase to sign the files. During the session I only have to do that once.

Now I've tried to make the signing unattended by creating this script that's called from my .bash_profile:

```
#!/bin/sh

OURKEY=ABCDEFGH
PASSPHRASE=my_passphrase
PIDOF=`pidof gpg-agent`
RETVAL=$?

# Decide wether to start gpg-agent daemon.
if [ "$RETVAL" -eq 1 ]; then
       echo "Starting gpg-agent daemon."
        eval `gpg-agent --allow-preset-passphrase --allow-mark-trusted --default-cache-ttl-ssh 4294967295 --default-cache-ttl 4294967295 --max-cache-ttl 4294967295 --daemon --enable-ssh-support --write-env-file "${HOME}/.gpg-agent-info"`
else
       echo "Daemon gpg-agent already running."
fi


if [ -f "${HOME}/.gpg-agent-info" ]; then
  . "${HOME}/.gpg-agent-info"
  export GPG_AGENT_INFO
  export SSH_AUTH_SOCK
  export SSH_AGENT_PID
  # Create necessary symbolic link
  cp -fs `echo $GPG_AGENT_INFO | cut -d':' -f 1` "${HOME}/.gnupg/"
fi

# Default trust our own key
rm ~/.gnupg/trustlist.txt
for FP in $(gpg2 --fingerprint --with-colons --fingerprint $OURKEY | grep ^fpr | cut -d':' -f 10); do
  echo "$FP S" >> ~/.gnupg/trustlist.txt
  echo $PASSPHRASE | /usr/lib/gnupg2/gpg-preset-passphrase --preset $FP
done

# Set GPG TTY
export GPG_TTY=$(tty)
```

I checked the fingerprints (a.k.a. keygrip, but this version of gpgsm does not know the --with-keygrip option) and all seems to be alright. However, when a cron job runs the above update command, an error message states that the passphrase is incorrect.

The server runs on Debian old-squeeze (I know, I have to do something about that, but that's another problem) and that might be a big problem. Here's some version info:

```
cat /etc/debian_version
6.0.10

uname -r
3.14.52-vs2.3.6.15-1

gpg (GnuPG) 1.4.10
gpg (GnuPG) 2.0.14
gpgsm (GnuPG) 2.0.14
gpg-agent (GnuPG) 2.0.14
```

So, is there somebody here who has some experience with unattended signing of packages with gpg-agent and can explain to me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: No, I have to do it manually.